# facebook instant articles How can I change the intensity of an ad?

Tags: facebook, facebook-instant-articles

facebook articles How can I change the advertising intensity?
for example, I want you to show me my ad in forty lines.

is there such a code? If so, where can I add this code to WordPress?

Answer (score 0):

The default (and automatic) ad density is one ad per 250 words and which is the highest ad density.

And if you manually insert multiple ad codes in an articles, the doc says:

> Automatic Ad Placement will be enabled if an article has more than one
>   ad for every 250 words or if ads exceed 20% percent of the total
>   content.

Please read doc here for more https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/monetization/ad-placement#automatic-placement